# amcharts - load ajax data

Tags: ajax, amcharts

I am using AMcharts to show the JSON data returned by my web server.  I am thinking of using the option like

```
chart.dataProvider : getData() { ... },
```

Here, I will make ajax call and return whatever data that the server sends. But the ajax call being asynchronous, I don't know know to how to supply the response data from the success function to the chart.

I contemplated on using dataLoader plugin, by supplying the url option like below..

```
"dataLoader" : {
    "url": "my_server_url"
    ...
}
```

but this approach won't work for me, as I have to send some additional auth headers to my webserver, which I can do in my own ajax call.

DataLoader plugin's ajax request doesn't seem to fire my global ajax before send callback, so I cannot hook it to send auth token.

Any help here...

Comment: I suppose the quickest way would be to start initializing the chart only **after** your asynchronous AJAX load completes. Alternative is to wait for an update to Data Loader plugin to come out that implements either auth or allows tinkering with the request before sending it to server. (I work for amCharts and I will forward this excellent idea to dev team)

Comment: I think, if AMCharts could support overridable ajax calls, similar to how Backbone.js does, it would be very useful.

Comment: Just to make sure, if there was an option to pass the XMLHttpRequest object through some custom callback function before opening it, would that be sufficient for you?

Comment: I think that should help. After your code triggers the callback, the invoked callback fn could modify the xmlhttprequest to add additional headers or change some data parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Building off what @martynasma said, here's a sample code snippet that worked for me...

```
    return jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'https://www.example.com/endpoint', //replace with your endpoint url
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // Add your parameters here
      },
    })
    .done( function( data ) {
      // Create the chart with data
      var chart = am4core.create( 'chartdiv', am4charts.PieChart );
      chart.data = data;

      // Add and configure Series
      var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
      pieSeries.dataFields.value = "liters";
      pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
    })
    .fail( function ( err ) {
      console.log( err );
    })
  }
  
  create_chart();
```